# extract newline text from string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have string as mentioned below:

> string=" (2021-07-04 11:58:43 PM BST)
> ---   len (Tradition ) says to sen Hi yohan
>
> (2021-07-05 12:04:42 AM BST)
> ---   len (Tradition) says to yohan   okay -5 / 0  .
>
> (2021-07-04 11:47:14 PM BST)
> ---   Ke Ch says to Hano   hello
>
> (2021-07-05 12:09:41 AM BST)
> ---   len says  to yohan sen   yes -5 / 0 TN -- / +2.5
>
> ---
>
> ---

```
Processed by wokl Archive for son malab | 2021-07-05 12:26:44 AM
BST  
---"
```

All I want to extract the text after says to and before timestamp.

Expected output as:

```
text=['yohan sen Hi yohan','yohan sen okay -5 / 0 ','Han Cho hello','sen yes -5 / 0 TN -- / +2.5']
```

What I have tried:

```
text=re.findall(r'\bsays to (.*(?:\n(?!\(\d|---).*?)*?)\s*\n(?:\(\d|---)', string)
```

Comment: Do you always want to extract what comes after "says to" and before the timestamp? And will the ext always be structured like this?

Comment: @Puff yes. I'm looking the same format. The regex what I have tried somewhat able to give me the required output but it gets failed where text starts from next line after `says to`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following Python code. Written and tested in Python3.

```
import re
##Create variable here string with user's values, since variable is too long so mentioning it as a comment here....
var1 = re.findall(r'says\s+[^(]*',string,re.M)
```

Above will create a list named `var1` whose elements will have new lines at last of each element, so to remove them use following code then. Using `strip` function of Python here.

```
var1 = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), var1))
```

Now print the all elements of `var1` list:

```
for element in var1:
    print (element)
```

***Explanation:*** Explanation of regex would be simple, using `re.findall` function of Python3 and mentioning regex to match `says\s+[^(]*` means match from says followed by space(s) just before next/1st occurrence of ( here.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```sh
says\s+to\s+((?:.+\n)+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3QoFAT/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `says\s+to\s+`: Matches `says to` followed by 1+ whitespaces
- `((?:.+\n)+)`: Match 1+ non-empty lines and capture in group #1

Python Code:

```sh
matches = re.findall(r'says\s+to\s+((?:.+\n)+)', string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=says\sto)[\s\S]*?(?=\(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s(\d\d:){2}\d{2}\s\w{2}\s\w{3}\))
```

You have to use look ahead and look behind regex for this. To solve your problem, you need one look behind, which is 'says to' and one look ahead which is the date pattern.

- Syntax for look behind is `(?<=fixed_length_regex)`
- Syntax for look ahead is `(?=fixed_length_regex)`

So essentially what you are looking for would look something like this:

```
   look-behind  |        pattern          |  look-ahead
________________|_________________________|__________________
                |                         |
(?<=(says\sto)) |  match_everything_here  | (?=date_pattern)
```

which is equivalent to first regex.

You can play around with the solution in regex101 here: https://regex101.com/r/rPFDo9/1/